# c# : Insert Image in MergeField Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge

I know how to programmaticaly add text in mergeField in Micorsoft Word, using this : https://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/create-a-word-document-from-a-template-using-c-mail-merge/

But, what I want is to add an image. Is it possible ? If not, how can I insert an image to a pre-defined position (in a Word template) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use bookmarks : please refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4f6ecdd-ede9-4f14-83c9-bcad018a444b/insert-image-at-bookmark-position-in-word-document-progamatically-c?forum=csharpgeneral

And, if the image doesn't show on Microsoft Word, here is a solution : http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/InvisibleGraphics.htm

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code uses Office COM, which means that MS Word has to be installed on the computer. If you would want to run this code on a server you would have to have MS Word installed there as well. This is not recommended (see Considerations for Server-side Automation of Office at http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

To run mail merge on the server, you have to use OpenXML which is tedious to implement. So if you have budget, solution to your problem is quite easy if you are willing to consider 3rd party tools (e.g. [Docentric](http://www.docentric.com)). With Docentric you could create a template and create a placeholder for the image in a template document and then merge the template and the image at runtime. Images can also be placed in headers and footers if needed. The toolkit also offers many other possibilities: tables, nested lists, charts, subdocuments, conditional content, any formatting that Word can do, headers, footers, sections, etc.